# Returning furnitures of each Person in the controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this controller and I would like to return each person's furniture. This 'chilren' method didn't work. The relationship between the two 'one to many' is working correctly. It isn't mandatory to use children method. Any resource to solve the problem is accetable.

**IMPORTANT:** Laravel Version 5.8

**PersonController.php**

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
        $person = Person::findOrFail($id);     
        $furnituresOfEachPerson = $person->childs();
        return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);      
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not triggering the query :

use this (with eager loading)

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
        $person = Person::with('childs')->findOrFail($id);     
        $furnituresOfEachPerson = $person->childs;
        return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);      
 }
```

or this : (calling the relationship directly)

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
        $person = Person::findOrFail($id);     
        $furnituresOfEachPerson = $person->childs()->get();
        return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);      
 }
```

or third option if the person->childs() relationship is a belongsTo :

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
        $furnituresOfEachPerson = Child::where('person_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);      
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage and disadvantage between the two examples provided by you?

Comment: In this context, it is quite the same, but in a general, I would use directly the object I want in the end, I add the third option, it allow to save one query to fetch the parent object